# How can I disable DNSSC for Google Apps (GMail) MX records on my authoritative domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, g-suite, gmail, dnssec

I'm running a BIND Master / Slave setup with DNSSEC, but some of my domains use Google Apps for e-mail services. Google doesn't support DNSSEC and BIND doesn't like it at all.

Log output:

```
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM/A/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM/AAAA/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755cb83950: ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM AAAA: bad cache hit (ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM/AAAA/IN': 69.147.224.178#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755ca52c30: ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM A: bad cache hit (ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM/A/IN': 69.147.224.178#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755ca52c30: ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM AAAA: bad cache hit (ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM/AAAA/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755cb83950: ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM A: bad cache hit (ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM/A/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f754c1b0bd0: ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM A: bad cache hit (ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM/A/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f754c1a6a30: ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM AAAA: bad cache hit (ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM/AAAA/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755cb83950: ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM AAAA: bad cache hit (ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
```

I'm not absolutely sure this is stopping Google Apps from working, because I just enabled all of the DNSSEC features. Does anyone here have experience with this?

Comment: Should not be a problem at all. What is your domain name? I'll check to see if anything is problematic with the DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the setup is that your zone has MX records pointing at Google's servers, there is no problem. The DNSSEC signatures for your zone validates the content of your MX records. That the content is another domain name that is not signed doesn't matter.